# psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "app_appfile" already exists

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I use postgres as DB for my project. I would like to make and run some test in my `test.py` file with sqlite DB. I change my `settings.py` file to do that with sqlite3 db, but when I try to run my simple test by `python manage.py test` I got this message:

Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: database "test_db" already exists

Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_db', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database for alias 'default'...

After 'yes' I got it

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "app_appfile" already exists

my app/test.py

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from . models import Level

class SearchTest(APITestCase):

    def test_find_out(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, 2)
```

my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': NAME,
        'USER': USER,
        'PASSWORD': PASSWORD,
        'PORT': PORT,
        'TEST': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': 'test_db',
        }
    }
}
SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False
```

I can see the same problem on the Internet but its solution doesn't work for me

Comment: 1) If you want the tests to be useful **do not** test against a different database product. In other words use a Postgres database as your test target not SQLite. 2) Look at the Postgres log to make sure you are not actually  connecting to it.

Comment: I resoloved by removing migrations. Now it is wokking well

Answer (score 0):

Your previous test run probably didn’t clean up well, you should try clearing any existing test database by running `python manage.py flush` and deleting your test database file manually by running `rm test_db` then finally, try running your tests again using `python manage.py test`.

Comment: I have just run: 
1. removed test_db in postgres
2. ran `python manage.py flush`
3. ran `python manage.py test`
I have the same issue 
`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "app_appfile" already exists`

Comment: I resoloved by removing migrations. Now it is wokking well